# 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/model'

Tags: python, macos, scipy, macos-mojave

```
import spacy
import random
nlp=spacy.load('en')

TRAIN_DATA = [(u"Uber blew through $1 million a week", {"entities": [(0, 4, "ORG")]}),(u"Google rebrands its business apps", {"entities": [(0, 6, "ORG")]})]

nlp = spacy.blank('en')
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
for i in range(20):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
        nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk("/model")
```

I tried to run the above-mentioned code on Python console with admin privileges but it displayed an error:

```
Warning: Unnamed vectors -- this won't allow multiple vectors models to be loaded. (Shape: (0, 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ss1.py", line 15, in <module>
    nlp.to_disk("/model")
  File "/Users/shailysaigal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 621, in to_disk
    util.to_disk(path, serializers, {p: False for p in disable})
  File "/Users/shailysaigal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 500, in to_disk
    path.mkdir()
  File "/Users/shailysaigal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1241, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/model'
```

I've given admin privileges and tried upgrading spaCy to v2.0.12.dev0.

Comment: Can you run `mkdir /model` at your OS prompt? If you can't, Python won't be able to create that directory either. This is an OS-permissions problem, not a Python problem. (That said, the right solution is not to give yourself more permissions, it's to try to save the data somewhere you actually have write access to; as someone with a security hat on, people who try to solve problems by throwing more permissions at it are one of my biggest source of headaches... and that's when we're lucky and it's just headaches, not actual exploited breaches).

Comment: I tried this command but it displays 'Permission denied' error.

Comment: There's your answer. If `mkdir` can't do it, why do you expect `python` should be able to?

Comment: (*why* you can't create new top-level directories on MacOS even when running as root would be a longer discussion going into Apple's platform protection / security functionality, but honestly, it's irrelevant; **just don't try to do that**).

Comment: ...which is to say, you should be saving your files in `/Users/shailysaigal/model`, not `/model`. If you use `./model` or just `model` instead of `/model` and run the script in your home directory, that's what it'll do out-of-the-box.